# Error when running RCLCPP examples on microROS workspace with rmw_microxrcedds

Tags: rclcpp, ament, micro-ros

I am trying to build rclcpp publisher subscriber example on microROS (host workspace on ubuntu:jammy). I am able to compile it (with -DRMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_microxrcedds) and run it for cyclonedds and rti_connext_dds but when I try to run with micro XRCE dds
I get the following error:

```
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_microxrcedds ros2 run ${project_name} ${executable_name}
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError' 

  what():  could not create service: Handle's typesupport identifier (rosidl_typesupport_cpp) is not supported by this library,at ~/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rosidl_typesupport/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/src/type_support_dispatch.hpp:111, at ~/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rcl/rcl/src/rcl/service.c:124 

[ros2run]: Aborted
```

While looking for issues I found that the package was using rosidl_typesupport_microxrcedds_c library. How do I specify it to use the cpp library instead? I tried adding build tag for rosidl_typesupport_microxrcedds_c in package.xml and used find_package() in CMakeLists.txt but it did not changed anything.
Any suggestions?